# Intersystems cache: project %ID in resultset using web services

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have a cache object class with 3 properties:

```
name
dob
address
```

When I return it as a resultset using a web service I get the 3 properties, as expected.

How do I also get the %ID in the XML projection, since the object is also persisted?

Comment: Just wanted to pass along a tip, since you're brand new to SO: it looks like Brandon's answer below was what you needed.  If you found that it solved your problem, it's appreciated that you mark his answer as the [accepted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that it helps out his reputation and also assists future people with the same problem.  At the same time, having a high question-to-accepted-answer ratio helps you too, since others will be more inclined to take the time to answer your questions in the future.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a property of type %XML.Id.

You can read documentation for this here:
http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GXMLPROJ_special#GXMLPROJ_C16628

Comment: Brandon, Thank you so much! I looked all over and could not find it. Cheers,